# When is RequireJS' require call asynchronous? When is it synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, require

I use RequireJS to load my modules in one of my projects. 
I see around the web different ways to require modules using the `require` call (and not `define`).

Lets assume I have a module named "JQuery" and I would like to require it.
Two ways are possible as I saw in examples:

1. This:

   ```
   require(["JQuery"], function($){
      $.doSomething();
   })
   ```
2. And this:

   ```
   var $ = require("JQuery");
   $.doSomething();
   ```

My question is if the load is async as RequireJS documantation says it is, how can the second convention work? How can I say for sure that `$` is defined and that the first row completed before the second row executes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RequireJS always loads modules asynchronously but it allow a form of `require` that looks synchronous. Your second snippet is actually missing some really important code. (Also, the module name for jQuery is hardcoded to `jquery`. You could write a configuration that allows you to refer to it as `jQuery` but there's no point.) This form of the `require` calls is designed to be used inside modules so:

```
define(function (require) {
    var $ = require("jquery");
    $.doSomething();
});
```

What RequireJS does with the code above is transform it into this before executing it:

```
define(['jquery'], function (require) {
    var $ = require("jquery");
    $.doSomething();
});
```

Note the addition of the dependency as the first argument of `define`. When RequireJS executes the code, it finds the dependency, loads `jquery` and then calls the anonymous function. By the time `require("jquery")` is encountered the module is already loaded. **At the end of the day while the `require` call *looks* synchronous, the loading of the module it requires still happens asynchronously.**

Can you use this synchronous form `require` outside of a `define` call? Only if you are okay with failures. **This `require` call will fail if the module passed to it is not already loaded.** You get the infamous error:

```
Module name ... has not been loaded yet for context: ...
```

Using it in a `define` like I've shown above is safe. Or I guess you could do:

```
require(['jquery'], function (require) {
    var $ = require("jquery");
    $.doSomething();
});
```

which *would* work but what's the point of manually repeating the dependency. (In case you wonder, RequireJS *does not* transform a `require` call with a callback like the one I have in my example here in the same way it transforms a `define` call as I've shown above.)

Comment: thank you. now its all clear, the code looks a bit nicer and cleaner in the second way as I see it. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to require.js docs it is a wrapper. So it is rebuilding code to work asynchronously. It is called CommonJs wrapper. You can find more info about it [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know requirejs. But I think it's possible to load module in both `sync` and `async` ways.

```
function require(name,cb){
    if(cb !== undefined){
        requireAsync(name,cb);
    }else{
        requireSync(name);
    }
}
```